# php wordpress - retrieveing values from mysql table one by one

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, algorithm

I have been trying to retrieve data one by one from mysql table that I just created. Below Image has shown the table that includes the sample coupon codes and a field called "test" to specify if the code has been generated by users.

My goal is to retrieve coupon codes below "adidas" serially (arda10, arda11, arda12,...) and update the status of the coupon in test column after the coupon code is shown.
If the status in test column is 1, the code should not be shown to the users. Only codes with status 0 should be printed.

```
$kupon = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `wp_kuponlar`', ARRAY_A);
echo $kupon[adidas];
```

Help please!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB1u1.png]

Comment: So is there an error or some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure what your question and what the error might be, but this is a better formating and way to go please ensure you adidas is qouted like the example I have below.

```
 $kupon = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_kuponlar', ARRAY_A);
     foreach($kupon as $coupon){
        echo $coupon['adidas'];
    }
```

**Extra tip**
 if the table is attached to wordpress db and not a totally different db, the better way to go is doing the following

```
 $kupon = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_kuponlar", ARRAY_A);
```

**Based on Comment**

```
 $kupon = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_kuponlar where status = 0 Orderby id ASC", ARRAY_A);
     foreach($kupon as $coupon){
        echo $coupon['adidas'];
    }
```

Comment: I just edited the mysql table, wp_kuponlar. see image here: ibb.co/ckpBRb What I want is: 1. show the codes in increasing order by their IDs. 2. update status field for each coupon and not show if the status if status is 1. UPDATE wp_kuponlar SET status='1' WHERE adidas='arda12'

Comment: Hi @ArdaUlusoy your question isn't so clear , but am going to update on my previous answer, from what I understand a little bit from you question. Please try and explain better especially the update aspect.

Comment: Hi @Ezekiel thank for your effort. I have a coupon code website created with WP. I am creating deals for my members and in each deal there are number (varies from deal to deal) of unique codes. I am uploading codes to wp_kuponlar table and each code has id (increasing order 1, 2, 3,...) and status (1 or 0; 1 for not used, 0 for used) value in the table. My goal is to retrieve a unique and not used code each time a user tries to see code. So, first user generates code will see first code in the table, second will see 2nd, 3rd will see 3rd. If a code has status 0, it should not be retrieved.

Comment: Hi @ArdaUlusoy I have changed my write up on retrieving all code that are not 0, but you can easy interchange between 0 and 1 in the code though. So it will retrieve the code in increasing number of the one's that are not 0, that is it will only show the ones with status 1

Answer (score 0):

Get results from wp database table use **$wpdb->get_results()** query something like this,

It gives you all your data with test status 0 or 1

```
 <?php

    global $wpdb;
    $kupon = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                    'SELECT * FROM wp_kuponlar'
            ), ARRAY_A
    );
    foreach ($kupon as $coupon) {
        echo $coupon['adidas'];
    }
```

but if you want to filter values for 0 only the change query as,

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$kupon = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM wp_kuponlar WHERE test = %d', 0
        ), ARRAY_A
);
foreach ($kupon as $coupon) {
    echo $coupon['adidas'];
}
```

**Find the result data set in order of coupons in ascending order** with test status not 1,

```
 <?php

global $wpdb;
$kupon = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT * FROM wp_kuponlar WHERE test != 1 ORDER BY RIGHT(adidas,3)'
        ), ARRAY_A
);
// Now the resultset will be in order of ids
foreach ($kupon as $coupon) {
    echo $coupon['adidas'];
}
```

Comment: hi Sanjay. Thanks for your answer. I got the point on how to bring status with it.but I have 2 peoblems: 1. arda11arda13arda14arda15arda16arda17arda18arda19arda2arda20arda3arda4arda5arda6arda7arda8arda9da1 2. I am stuck at bringing the values on the table one by one.

Comment: Let me help you @ArdaUlusoy, please make me clear about your comment as ' If the status in test column is 1, the code should not be shown to the users. Only codes with status 0 should be printed.' what does it mean?

Comment: Sure. I just edited the mysql table, wp_kuponlar. see image here: https://ibb.co/ckpBRb
What I want is: 
1. show the codes in increasing order by their IDs.
2. update status field for each coupon and not show if the status if status is 1.
UPDATE `wp_kuponlar` SET status='1' WHERE adidas='arda12'

Comment: now @ArdaUlusoy, i have added one more script which actually gives you the result in order of coupons.